# Inject in EntityListener

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, entity

I have a  problem when i try start the server JBoss 7.0, because throws error.
This happens when put the entityListiner on Entity.

is possible inject in the entity Listener?

Trace:

```
MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."pagos-0.8.105.war#pagos_PU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."pagos-0.8.105.war#pagos_PU": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pagos_PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:667)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: pagos_PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001456: Argument resolvedBean must not be null
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Preconditions.checkArgumentNotNull(Preconditions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:794)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:363)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:374)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl$ListenerImpl.<init>(ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl$ListenerImpl.<init>(ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.buildListener(ListenerFactoryBeanManagerStandardImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.resolveCallbacks(CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.buildCallbacksForEntity(CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator.integrate(JpaIntegrator.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners({Listener.class})
public class DetalleBeca implements Serializable {
...
..
}
```

Listener:

```
public class Listener {
@Inject
private LogFacade logFacade;    

@PostRemove
public void metodoRemover(DetalleBeca detalle) throws LogException {
        logfacade.reg(detalle)
        System.out.println(detalle);
}
```

Comment: there seems to be a bug in EAP 7.0, this did't happen with  EAP 7.1 BETA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. It is a bug in EAP 7.0. Here are the tickets : [JBEAP-5371](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBEAP-5371),[WFLY-2387](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2387)